# Latest WhatsApp Desktop from App Store crashes on High Sierra

Tags: high-sierra, mac-appstore, software-update, crash, whatsapp.app

WhatsApp Desktop from the Mac App Store no longer launches after the July 20, 2020 update to version 2.2029.4.

System information:
MacOS 10.13.6 High Sierra with all system updates installed
WhatsApp for Mac 2.2029.4 (Mac App Store installation)

[image]

Symptoms:
A white screen opens then a message briefly appears "WhatsApp needed to restart because of a problem."  The application then quits. Sometimes it is accompanied by a Mac crash report.

Troubleshooting steps:

- Deleting and reinstalling from the Mac App store does not resolve
- Deleting ~/Library/Containers/desktop.WhatsApp and relaunching does not resolve

Comment: Did you approach their Customer Support on this already? What was the answer you got there?

Comment: Please see https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y on how to resolve basic customer support issues and what is required to have it reopened.

Comment: @mamawildbear Can you post your solution as an answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to version 2.2029.5 released today fixed everything, it was indeed a bug on their previous build.